# NodeJS - Logging Winston out to syslog on OSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, syslog, winston

I've been trying to get my NodeJS application logging into syslog for days now with no apparent success:

```
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-syslog').Syslog; // eslint-disable-line

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
let syslogConfig = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 514,
    "protocol": "unix",
    "path": "/var/run/syslog"
};

const logger = new winston.Logger({
    levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
    colors: winston.config.syslog.colors
});

logger.add(winston.transports.Syslog, syslogConfig);

logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
    json: false,
    colorize: true,
    timestamp: true
});

logger.error('Hello, world!');

module.exports = logger;
```

When this code runs I get no errors in my terminal (it compiles just fine, and I see "Hello, world!" in my terminal output) but I never see anything logged in my OSX Console app under `syslog` process.

On the other hand I can manually run `syslog -s -l ERROR “Hello, world.”` in my terminal and it shows up in Console app.

I'm pretty stumped here -- I'm running OSX Sierra (10.12.6)

Comment: Hi! Have you found solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope. It seems like my logs appear in `syslog` just fine when I deploy to Linux server, but they never show up in OSX Console app.

Comment: Thank you. I have very similar resolution. In my case when I've used a `unix` protocol, logs appeared fine except logs with a severity `info` & `debug`, I'm talking `syslog` severities set. When I started to push logs to linux by using `udp` protocol all worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's been years since this message.
I finally got something working so thought I should share:

```
const winston = require('winston')
require('winston-syslog').Syslog

// Logger creation
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
})

// Console feedback
logger.add(
  new winston.transports.Console({
    name: 'consoleLogs'
  })
)

// Sending to syslog
logger.add(
  new winston.transports.Syslog({
    protocol: 'unix',
    path: '/var/run/syslog'
  })
)

// Test message
logger.alert('Hello world!!')
```

I can see the message `/var/log/system.log`